# XSLT 1.0: Is it possible to remove content inside parenthesis from a string?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking to remove content inside parenthesis and only display the original content. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Lite Version="0.0.0">
    <LogEventCollection>
        <LogEvent Type="SONG" ScheduledTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" StartTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" StartTimeLocal="10/15/2015 4:00:00 PM" Chain="SEGUE" Status="CURRENT" Duration="02:40">
        <Asset Type="SONG" AssetTypeName="Song" Title="Title (Extra Info)" Artist1="ArtistHere" ThirdPartyId="SongA" TotalLength="160"/>
        <NotesCollection>
            <Note Title="Note 1" Script="Note 1' Script"/>
            <Note Title="Note 2"/>
        </NotesCollection>
        </LogEvent>
    </LogEventCollection>
</Lite>
```

I am looking to display `"Title"` without the extra information inside of the parenthesis. I attempted using translate but I am unsure of how to select the information inside as well. Here is my current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline">
    <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="LogEventCollection">
    <xsl:variable name="TITLE" select="LogEvent/Asset/@Title"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="LogEvent">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Type='SONG'">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($TITLE, '(*)','')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, as you can imagine, this only strips the parenthesis and not the content inside. Currently displaying `Title Extra Info` looking to display only `Title`.

Comment: Will there always be exactly one pair of parentheses in the `Title`?

Comment: Yes and no, if the parentheses exist there will only be one pair. But they will not always exist. I'm using this to send song metadata to an RDS unit to display metadata. For example I am currently exporting `Nicki Minaj - Super Bass (Super Clean)` but would like to remove the ending (Super Clean) from the export.

Comment: Minor aside, but all the answers here will leave a trailing space in the sample given, and if parentheses were in the middle you could end up with a double space left behind. That might not be a problem for you, but if needed you can trim and remove double spaces using the `normalize-space` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a twice shorter solution** (working correctly when the assumption that at most one pair of left->right parenthesis exist per `@Title` attribute:)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/LogEvent[@Type='SONG']/Asset[@Type='SONG']/@Title"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@Title">
    <xsl:variable name="vLeft" select="substring-before(concat(.,'('), '(')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vRight" 
         select="substring-after(substring-after(., concat($vLeft, '(')), ')')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($vLeft, $vRight, '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this source XML document** (the provided one extended to cover all possible cases):

```
<Lite Version="0.0.0">
    <LogEventCollection>
        <LogEvent Type="SONG" 
        ScheduledTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTimeLocal="10/15/2015 4:00:00 PM" 
        Chain="SEGUE" 
        Status="CURRENT" 
        Duration="02:40">
            <Asset Type="SONG" 
            AssetTypeName="Song" 
            Title="Title1 Left (Extra Info)" 
            Artist1="ArtistHere"
            ThirdPartyId="SongA"
            TotalLength="160"/>
            <NotesCollection>
                <Note Title="Note 1" Script="Note 1' Script"/>
                <Note Title="Note 2"/>
            </NotesCollection>
        </LogEvent>
        <LogEvent Type="SONG" 
        ScheduledTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTimeLocal="10/15/2015 4:00:00 PM" 
        Chain="SEGUE" 
        Status="CURRENT" 
        Duration="02:40">
            <Asset Type="SONG" 
            AssetTypeName="Song" 
            Title="Title2 (Extra Info) surround" 
            Artist1="ArtistHere"
            ThirdPartyId="SongA"
            TotalLength="160"/>
            <NotesCollection>
                <Note Title="Note 1" Script="Note 1' Script"/>
                <Note Title="Note 2"/>
            </NotesCollection>
        </LogEvent>
        <LogEvent Type="SONG" 
        ScheduledTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTimeLocal="10/15/2015 4:00:00 PM" 
        Chain="SEGUE" 
        Status="CURRENT" 
        Duration="02:40">
            <Asset Type="SONG" 
            AssetTypeName="Song" 
            Title="(Extra Info)Title3 Right" 
            Artist1="ArtistHere"
            ThirdPartyId="SongA"
            TotalLength="160"/>
            <NotesCollection>
                <Note Title="Note 1" Script="Note 1' Script"/>
                <Note Title="Note 2"/>
            </NotesCollection>
        </LogEvent>
        <LogEvent Type="SONG" 
        ScheduledTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTime="2015-10-15T22:00:00.0004997Z" 
        StartTimeLocal="10/15/2015 4:00:00 PM" 
        Chain="SEGUE" 
        Status="CURRENT" 
        Duration="02:40">
            <Asset Type="SONG" 
            AssetTypeName="Song" 
            Title="Title4 No brackets" 
            Artist1="ArtistHere"
            ThirdPartyId="SongA"
            TotalLength="160"/>
            <NotesCollection>
                <Note Title="Note 1" Script="Note 1' Script"/>
                <Note Title="Note 2"/>
            </NotesCollection>
        </LogEvent>
    </LogEventCollection>
</Lite>
```

**The wanted, correct result (for all `Title` attributes) is produced**:

```
Title1 Left 
Title2  surround
Title3 Right
Title4 No brackets
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @Title,'(' ), substring-after( @Title,')' ) )" />
```

The `substring-after()` is only needed if there is a string after the closing parenthesis

Update (fix doe to the perfect answer form Dimitre Novatchev):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
                     substring-before( concat( @Title, '(') ,'(' ), 
                     substring-after( @Title,')' ) )" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Lite">
    <xsl:for-each select="LogEventCollection/LogEvent[@Type='SONG']">
        <xsl:variable name="TITLE" select="Asset/@Title"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($TITLE, '(') and contains($TITLE, ')')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($TITLE, '(')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($TITLE, ')')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Strictly speaking, one should test that the closing parenthesis comes *after* the opening one, but...

Comment: @JasonBond If you want to confirm that you have a single pair of parentheses in the correct order, you can use 'double translate' method to check if everything but the parenthesis equals `()`, like this: `translate(translate(@Title,'()',''),'') = '()'`. The inner translate returns everything except the parentheses, the outer one translates all of these characters to nothing, leaving just the parenthesis. XPath 2 has more robust solutions with regex, if you ever upgrade.

Comment: @JasonBond I would not switch if I were you. I prefer readable code.